# how to Adjust dashboardSidebar heigth

Tags: css, r, shiny, shinydashboard

So recently i adjust my header heigth for my shiny web app using style.css and the code is like this

```
/* header title font */
.skin-blue .main-header .logo {
  height: 20vh;
}

.skin-blue .main-header .navbar {
  min-height: 20vh;
}
```

and then this is what happens
[image]

the header is blocking my first sidebar tab I want to adjust the height so it becomes more lower so but I have no idea how to change the sidebar height because by default the package only offer you to adjust  the width, and the sidebar icon also getting smaller I want to know how to make that icon larger too

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: have you tried adding `margin-top: 20vh` to the sidebar?